# Query Result into JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to store the query result for the below query

```
"SELECT sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%abcd%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'abcd',
        sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%gef%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'gef',
        sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%hij%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'hij',
        sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%lmn%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'lmn' from events"
```

as JSON in the form

```
{'abcd': 1, 'gef' : 2, 'hij' : 1, 'lmn' : 3}
```

in Rails.

I use     `count_result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` which returns only the values and not the keys.
I get the results in the format [1,2,1,3].

How to obtain the key values and store them into json format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query` to get a [`ActiveRecord::Result`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Result.html) object which can be turned into a hash:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("SELECT sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%abcd%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'abcd',
        sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%gef%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'gef',
        sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%hij%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'hij',
        sum( CASE WHEN properties like '%lmn%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'lmn' from events")

result.to_h # => { 'abcd' => 1, 'hij' => 0 ... }
```

To convert the values to a JSON string you just call `.to_json` on the hash. But if you are using a native JSON column type you do not need to manually convert it.